# Null Pointer Exception Error on MainActivity that unable to start the whole app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm doing an application whereby there is a login in page and user will be prompt to enter their username and password.
After that, it will take the username entered to another new page that will display "Welcome ".
In this page, it will show a list of categories of charts that the user can choose to view it.
However, when I tried to run it, the app keep crash.
And I run the debug, it says that it was a NullPointerException.

The log cat show as above:

```
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): Process: com.nyp.exploregowhere, PID: 1173
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nyp.exploregowhere/com.nyp.exploregowhere.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.nyp.exploregowhere.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-02 10:25:23.826: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
```

And this is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    userNameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameET);
    LoginBT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginBT);

    LoginBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("username", userNameET.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,LOGIN_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE);
        }

    });


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The new error codes after changing:

```
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
07-02 11:15:50.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1444):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It looks like the null pointer exception happened on line 26. Which line does this correspond to in the code you posted?

Comment: the line is "Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);"

Answer (score 0):

The super.onCreate and the setContentView need to be called first in onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userNameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameET);
    LoginBT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginBT);

    LoginBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("username", userNameET.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,LOGIN_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: there's an error that says: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<LoginActivity>) is undefined

Comment: Quite correct. Apologies I forgot the intent was within the OnClickListener. I've edited the answer with a better solution.

Comment: Do you mean the solution in green highlighted?

Comment: The one that reads "Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),LoginActivity.class);"

Comment: Are you getting an error in trying to use getBaseContext() or is it still crashing?

Comment: it is still crashing.. The app is unable to start

Comment: Aha. I've recreated. Will edit answer with solution above. You need to call the super.onCreate and setContentView earlier.

Comment: Ahhh Yes ! It worked ! May I ask another question? How to intent from listview to a chart activity by hardcoding?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly. You would create a ListView item in your activity and use listView.setOnItemClickListener to specify how to handle clicks. In here you could launch an intent as before.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following lines inside onCreate method.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

It assumes that the corresponding xml file is `activity_main.xml`.
Make sure to add this statements just above

```
userNameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameET);
```

Please comment if you get any error.